# Stop silverlight or wpf usercontrols from loading in the toolbox?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have a project with 100's of usercontrols. When I load the project in VS2010 and try to open a designer, the toolbox spins and spins until they're all loaded.

Winforms has a "AutoToolboxPopulate" switch under Tools/Options/Winddows Forms Designer/General.

I cannot find a similar switch for the XAML designer. Does one exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2010, the Auto Populate Toolbox switch for XAML can be found under Tools/Options/Text Editor/XAML/Miscellaneous.

If you wish to keep the Auto Populate enabled, you can decorate your usercontrol classes with the [System.ComponentModel.DesignTimeVisibleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designtimevisibleattribute.aspx) which will allow you to specify if they appear or not in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't one that I am aware of, with the exception of actually adding a design-time (*.Design.dll) assembly for the project that effectively defines metadata to hide the explicit controls.

This bit me as well recently and I wish I had a solution like the old winforms attribute!